# jQuery preventDefault function not working on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot get the following simple jQuery to work. I know I am overlooking something, so please help me out. Here is the code at http://jsfiddle.net/Z5waA/. It's a simple click the button, then alert with jQuery.

Comment: It won't help that you're not including the jQuery library in the JSFiddle.

Comment: It's `e.preventDefault()`. Note that opening your JavaScript console would have shown you this immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preventDefault(e);` should be `e.preventDefault();`

code should be like this,

```
$('#submitResetPass').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
});
```

and you need to add jQuery reference.

Comment: OMG! Besides the e.preventDefault deal, I had MOOTOOLS selected in jSfiddle! WOW! thanks Chamika!

Comment: Chamika: really, no need to beg for upvotes/accepts - the asker/community are able to decide for themselves...

Comment: @Konerak: see the first comment, he accept the answer but not marked yet. that's why i ask for it

Answer (score 1):

You had a couple issues.  First, the jsFiddle wasn't set for jQuery.  Then, your call to preventDefault wasn't correct.  It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v9aVb/.

```
$('#submitResetPass').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault() instead of preventDefault(e).